# Latest WebKit breaks the authorization process and freezes the JavaScript's main thread?

Tags: javascript, webkit

I have very trivial login form with 'username'/'pass' input fields and 'Login' button. When the user clicks 'Login', I send the fetch() request to the backend. Well, the backend responds to the client with status code 401 if there was an incorrect input for username or password.

Literally today I've discovered that all the latest versions of WebKit based browsers (at least under MacOS) by receiving the status 401 will show the system pop-up with two inputs (login/pass) and two buttons (Cancel/OK). Affected are Google Chrome, Opera and Safari. (Mozilla Firefox and MS Edge are OK!)

The most 'funny' thing is that Google Chrome 69 additionally freezes the JavaScript's main thread until one of buttons in mentioned above system pop-up is pressed. (Btw, Chrome 66 does nothing like that)

For now I've found only one workaround: change all 401 statuses on backend to something non standard like 471...

So I actually have two questions at once:

1) if somebody knows the better solution of described problem, it will be highly appreciated and big thanks in advance

2) it would be very interesting to know why and whats for the WebKit's developers have done so